# how to fix: ParseException: mismatched input 'FROM' expecting <EOF>(line 87, pos 4)

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I am running a task to load data in a table, everything seems to be fine , but I keep getting an error of:

```
select 
aa.source as source
,aa.Opportunity as Opportunity
,concat(substring(aa.create_date,1,4),'-',substring(aa.create_date,5,2),'-',substring(aa.create_date,7,2),'T',substring(aa.create_time,1,2),':',substring(aa.create_time,3,2),':',substring(aa.create_time,5,2),'.000Z') as Create_Date
,concat(substring(aa.submit_date,1,4),'-',substring(aa.submit_date,5,2),'-',substring(aa.submit_date,7,2),'T',substring(aa.submit_time,1,2),':',substring(aa.submit_time,3,2),':',substring(aa.submit_time,5,2),'+8:00') as Submit_Date
,aa.Bid_Reference_Number as Bid_Reference_Number
,aa.Bid_Reference_Number_Item as Bid_Reference_Number_Item
,aa.Solution_ID as Solution_ID
,aa.Config_ID  as Config_ID
,aa.LeROM_ID   as LeROM_ID
,concat(substring(aa.contract_start_date,1,4),'-',substring(aa.contract_start_date,5,2),'-',substring(aa.contract_start_date,7,2),'T00:00:00.000Z') as frontend_contract_start_date
,concat(substring(aa.Contract_Start_Date_in_Quotation,1,4),'-',substring(aa.Contract_Start_Date_in_Quotation,5,2),'-',substring(aa.Contract_Start_Date_in_Quotation,7,2),'T',substring(aa.zstrttime,1,2),':',substring(aa.zstrttime,3,2),':',substring(aa.zstrttime,5,2),'+8:00')as frontend_contract_start_date_in_quotation  --时间可以需要将 20170404  转2017-04-04 
,concat(substring(aa.Contract_End_Date_in_Quotation,1,4),'-',substring(aa.Contract_End_Date_in_Quotation,5,2),'-',substring(aa.Contract_End_Date_in_Quotation,7,2),'T',substring(aa.zendtime,1,2),':',substring(aa.zendtime,3,2),':',substring(aa.zendtime,5,2),'+8:00') as frontend_contract_end_date_in_quotation  --可以   
,aa.Contract_ID as Contract_ID
,aa.Contract_Item as Contract_Item
,aa.Contract_Status    as Contract_Status
,null as Backend_Contract_Start_Date
,null as Backend_Contract_Start_Date_in_Quotation
,null as Backend_Contract_End_Date_in_Quotation
,null as Backend_Contract_ID
,null as Backend_Contract_Item
,null as Backend_Contract_Status   
,aa.Quote_Description   as Quote_Description
,aa.Quotation_Transaction_Type as Quotation_Transaction_Type
,aa.Quotation_Transaction_Type_Medium_Name as Quotation_Transaction_Type_Medium_Name
,aa.Product_ID_Medium_Name   as Product_ID_Medium_Name
,aa.Product_ID_Key      as Product_ID_Key
,aa.Product_ID  as Product_ID
,aa.Product_Description as Product_Description
,aa.Quotation_Quantity  as Quotation_Quantity
,aa.Currency   as Currency
,aa.web_Price  as web_Price
,aa.Web_price_in_USD    as Web_price_in_USD
,aa.Channel_Price as Channel_Price
,aa.Channel_Price_in_USD as Channel_Price_in_USD
,aa.Quote_Price_or_Discount  as Quote_Price_or_Discount
,aa.Quote_Price_or_Discount_in_USD as Quote_Price_or_Discount_in_USD
,aa.Standard_Price      as Standard_Price
,aa.Standard_Price_in_USD    as Standard_Price_in_USD
,aa.Bid_Price  as bid_Price
,aa.Bid_Price_in_USD   as bid_Price_in_USD 
,aa.TMC as TMC
,aa.TMC_in_USD as TMC_in_USD
,aa.Net_Value  as Net_Value
,aa.Net_Value_in_USD as Net_Value_in_USD
,null as net_price 
,null as net_price_in_usd  
,aa.Actual_Revenue      as Actual_Revenue
,aa.Actual_Revenue_in_USD  as Actual_Revenue_in_USD
,null as margin_np_percent   
,null as margin_usd  
,null as total_margin_usd  
,null as total_margin_usd_in_usd   
,null as margin_np_in_usd     
,aa.GP  as GP
,aa.gp_in_usd  as gp_in_usd
,concat(Cast(cast(GP/CASE WHEN (case when aa.Actual_Revenue is null then 0 else aa.Actual_Revenue end)=0 OR Actual_Revenue = 0 THEN 1 ELSE (case when aa.Actual_Revenue is null then 0 else aa.Actual_Revenue end) END*100 as decimal(18,2)) as string),'%') AS GP_percentage      
,concat(round(((1-(aa.Bid_Price/CASE WHEN (case when aa.Web_Price is null then 0 else aa.Web_Price end)=0 OR aa.Web_Price = 0 THEN 1 ELSE (case when aa.Web_Price is null then 0 else aa.Web_Price end)END))*100),2),'%') AS DOL      
,aa.Bid_Status_Changed_on   as Bid_Status_Changed_on 
,aa.Bid_Status  as Bid_Status
,aa.Bid_Status_Long_Name as Bid_Status_Long_Name
,concat(substring(aa.date_approved,1,4),'-',substring(aa.date_approved,5,2),'-',substring(aa.date_approved,7,2),'T',substring(aa.approved_time,1,2),':',substring(aa.approved_time,3,2),':',substring(aa.approved_time,5,2),'.000Z') as Date_Approved
,aa.Approving_Status     as Approving_Status
,aa.Approving_Status_Long_Name as Approving_Status_Long_Name
,aa.Approval_Result    as Approval_Result 
,aa.Approval_Comment    as Approval_Comment 
,aa.Comment_Special    as Comment_Special 
,aa.Last_Pricer_Status  as Last_Pricer_Status
,aa.Last_Pricer_Status_Long_Name as Last_Pricer_Status_Long_Name
,aa.Sold_To    as Sold_To
,aa.Sold_To_Long_Name  as Sold_To_Long_Name
,ZBPLI_SR.nielsen_id as end_customer_Nielson_ID 
,aa.End_Customer as End_Customer
,aa.End_Customer_Long_Name   as End_Customer_Long_Name
,aa.Sales_Org  as Sales_Org
,aa.CRM_Sales_Org_Name  as CRM_Sales_Org_Name
,aa.Distribution_Channel as Distribution_Channel
,aa.Distribution_Channel_Name as Distribution_Channel_Name
,aa.User_Name  as create_by
,aa.Bid_Approver_First_Name   as Bid_Approver_First_Name
,aa.Bid_Approver_Last_Name   as Bid_Approver_Last_Name
,aa.Sales_Rep  as Sales_Rep
,aa.Sales_Rep_First_Name as Sales_Rep_First_Name
,aa.Sales_Rep_Last_Name  as Sales_Rep_Last_Name
,aa.Sales_Rep_Description    as Sales_Rep_Description 
,aa.Re_Bid    as Re_Bid 
,aa.Indirect_SBO as Indirect_SBO
,aa.SALESOFFCIE as SALESOFFCIE
,aa.SALES_OFFICE_DESCRIPTION as SALES_OFFICE_DESCRIPTION
,aa.Sub_Geo    as Sub_Geo
,aa.GEO as GEO
,aa.COUNTRY    as COUNTRY
,case when aa.Sales_Org in ('TH10' ,'ID90' ,'TW10','BR10') then  case when aa.Create_Date<20170101 then null else case when (aa.prodh1=7 or aa.prodh2='5EPG') then 'DCG' else null end end else aa.DCG_FLAG end as DCG_FLAG  
,aa.Original_Req_Price  as Original_Req_Price
,aa.Original_Req_Price_in_USD as Original_Req_Price_in_USD
,aa.Approved_Price      as Approved_Price
,aa.Approved_Price_in_USD as Approved_Price_in_USD
,null as apttus_config2_linetype 
,null as Approval_Level
,null as brand 
,null as apttus_qpconfig_configurationfinalizeddate 
,null as configurationfinalizeddate
,null as Feasibility
,null as FULFILLMENT_Method
,null as DEAL_REG
,null as PROPOSAL_PRESENTED_DATE
,null as Account_owner
,null as Account_name
,null as normal_path
,null as CTO_flag
,null as Custom_Model_for_MTM_only
,null as RPQ
,null as New_Custom_PN
,null as Product_Type
,'ThinkServer' as ThinkServer 
,'feasibility_approval_required' as feasibility_approval_required
,null as productgroupcode
,null as quotation_key_name
,null as quotation_key_frontend_contract_no
,null as quotation_key_backend_contract_no
,null as approvalrequest_key_Apttus_QPApprov_ProposalId
,null as productconfiguration_key_Apttus_QPConfig_Proposald   
,null as productconfiguration_key_apttus_config2_productconfiguration_id
,null as productconfiguration_key_id
,null as lineitem_key_Apttus_Config2_configurationId   
,null as lineitem_key_Name
,null as lineitem_key_Apttus_Config2_ProductId
,null as proposallineitem_key_Apttus_QPConfig_DerivedFromId
,null as pricingcontract_key_contract_number
,'' as sub_type
,'' as `gtn%`
from 
proj_sbtt.T1 aa
left join
proj_sbtt.bw_ms_zoozbplil_odl ZBPLI_SR
ON aa.End_Customer=ZBPLI_SR.ZBPLI
```

> `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
>   mismatched input 'FROM' expecting <EOF>(line 87, pos 4)`

This is for Spark sql and previously worked without issue

Comment: You'd have to narrow it down yourself. Try looking at the offending line (or nearby), it might contain some (invisible) control character that throws the reader off, or perhaps some other screwball character. Or some parenthesis isn't properly closed, missing punctuation, query is just too long.

Comment: query has comment "--可以" on line 13

Comment: Did you get the reason for this ? i am also having same issue.